# MPI Ring Leader Election returns segmentation fault

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing, mpich, leader

This is what I am trying to achieve.

```
Blue is the message.
Yellow is when the specific node changes the leader known to it.
Green is the final election of each node.
```

[image]

The code seems correct to me but it's always stuck inside the while loop no matter what I tried. For a small number of nodes during runtime it returns a segmentation fault after a while.

```
election_status=0;
firstmsg[0]=world_rank;     // self rank
firstmsg[1]=0;              // counter for hops
chief=world_rank;           // each node declares himself as leader
counter=0;                  // message counter for each node

// each node sends the first message to the next one
MPI_Send(&firstmsg, 2, MPI_INT, (world_rank+1)%world_size, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Sent ID with counter to the right node [%d -> %d]\n",world_rank, (world_rank+1)%world_size);

while (election_status==0){
    // EDIT: Split MPI_Recv for rank 0 and rest
    if (world_rank==0){
        MPI_Recv(&incoming, 2, MPI_INT, world_size-1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    else {
        MPI_Recv(&incoming, 2, MPI_INT, (world_rank-1)%world_size, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    counter=counter+1;
    if (incoming[0]<chief){
        chief=incoming[0];
    }
    incoming[1]=incoming[1]+1;

    // if message is my own and hopped same times as counter
    if (incoming[0]==world_rank && incoming[1]==counter) {
        printf("Node %d declares node %d a leader.\n", world_rank, chief);  
        election_status=1;
    }
    //sends the incremented message to the next node
    MPI_Send(&incoming, 2, MPI_INT, (world_rank+1)%world_size, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: If you can't go out of the while loop, it means that you never go into the second if( ).  So you need to understand why.

Comment: it seems curious to me, the counter and incoming[1] are being incremented without a stop. Why is that when theoretically there should be a continuation on the commands executed by each node? Shouldn't the counter=counter+1 command be executed for each node, after the node received a message?

Comment: Hey, your `(world_rank-1)` for `MPI_Recv` looks not very good. Think about root with `rank=0`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem, I split the receive into 2 ifs and it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine some minimum number among a number of ranks for all ranks, use `MPI_Allreduce`!

- `MPI_Send` is blocking. It can block forever until a matching receive is posted. Your program deadlocks on the first call to MPI_Send - and any successive once should it complete by coincidence. To avoid that specifically use `MPI_Sendrecv`.
- `(world_rank-1)%world_size` will produce `-1` for `world_rank == 0`. Using `-1` as rank number is not valid. It might coincidentially be `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`.

Comment: I split the receive into 2 ifs. It's working beautifully... Thanks!

Comment: Your program is still incorrect! Do not rely on the nonblocking behavior that `MPI_Send` sometimes exhibits. Use `MPI_Sendrecv` for a portable conforming program.